# How do I create a Help document for my software using Qt?

Tags: qt

How do I create a Help document for my software using Qt?

For example, if you press F1 in a program, I want to show the relevant help to the user.

Is there any preferred way, whether it's xml or html? .chm?

What methods do Qt developers use?

Comment: The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthelp-framework.html) have plenty to say about that.

Comment: See https://www.walletfox.com/course/qhelpengineexample.php